# how to get jwt token from access token in auth0

Tags: node.js, angular, token, jwt, auth0

I am developing angular2-nodejs-mongodb single page application.and using auth0 security.

I got **access_token** from angular2 project. But it's not **jwt_token**. Main problem is node.js project want jwt_token like **Authorization : Bearer My_Token**. Attached image below.

Angular image :getting access_token

[image]

postman:send requires to auth0 for jwt_token

[image]

postman : try to access my nodejs aaplication

[image]

Actually I did't get idea, how to convert angular access token to node.js jwt_tocken

Comment: share your code here.

Comment: just created project from git angular2 : https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples

Comment: nodejs : https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-express-api-samples

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say I found this solution on internet

> Actually copied some code from private repo)

```
const createClient = () => createAuth0Client({
  domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  client_id: AUTH0_ID,
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
});

...

export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    public sessionService: SessionService,
    public alertService: AlertService,
    public userService: UserService,
  ) {
    makeObservable(this, {
      sessionService: observable,
      alertService: observable,
      userService: observable,
      authPopup: action.bound,
      authRedirect: action.bound,
      _handleNewToken: action.bound,
      init: action.bound,
    });
    this.init();
  }

  async _handleNewToken(auth0: Auth0Client) {
    const {
      _raw: jwt,
      nickname,
      picture,
      email,
    } = await auth0.getIdTokenClaims();
    nickname && this.userService.setNickname(nickname);
    picture && this.userService.setPicture(picture);
    email && this.userService.setEmail(email);
    this.sessionService.setSessionId(jwt);
    //                               ^^^
  }

  async authPopup() {
    let token: string | false = false;
    try {
      const auth0 = await createClient();
      await auth0.loginWithPopup();
      await this._handleNewToken(auth0);
      this.alertService.push('Signed in successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.alertService.push('Authorization failed');
    } finally {
      return token;
    }
  }

  async authRedirect() {
    try {
      const auth0 = await createClient();
      await auth0.loginWithRedirect();
      await sleep(5_000);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.alertService.push('Authorization failed');
    }
  }

  async init() {
    try {
      const auth0 = await createClient();
      await auth0.handleRedirectCallback();
      await this._handleNewToken(auth0);
      this.alertService.push('Signed in successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

};

...

const handleButtonClick = () => {
        await authService.authRedirect();
        ...
};
```